What exception guarantee level does std::vector::operator=() have?
When I assign one std::vector to another std::vector, and std::bad_alloc raises internally, does the C++ specification guarantee that my vector will be left in the correct state? Does it have a basic or maybe strong exception guarantee?
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b = {4, 5, 6};

try {
    a = b;
} catch (std::bad_alloc& e){
    for (int el: a)
        std::cout << el << "\n";
}

What will be the output if b could not be copied to a?

One would hope that the vector would catch the error internally and set itself to empty before rethrowing, that should be easy to do.

@BoP I looked over that question and answer.  The answers there do not answer the OP's question (except by external reference), and the level of detail you'd have to insert into that Q&A so it answers questions at the detail the OP requests would be substantial.  Or maybe I missed it?  And of the references, which and where?  I glanced at Bjarn's PDF, and the table doesn't clearly describe the guarantees of operator=.  So

@MarkRansom Maybe I'm not understanding you properly, but what if the destination vector was already populated?

OP, well done, I'm glad this made it out of the staging area

@catnip I guess that would be acceptable as well, if the vector simply maintained its previous state.  The thing you want to avoid is having it be invalid by setting its internal pointer to a failed allocation.

@MarkRansom Sure, but that's the OP's question.  Does it in fact do that?  Can that be relied upon?  I mean, it wouldn't be hard for std::vector to offer such a guarantee (it's just a couple of pointer swaps), but it would be expensive, in terms of potential peak memory use, so there's a price to pay.  Heh, fail early and fail often - die on bad_alloc.
